# Searching and Replacing Null Value

Tags: case, isnull

I'm looking to check my SourceCode variable for Null values and then convert all Nulls to the text value BaseSource. Before I run this on live data I want to make sure that is what the following code will do:

> ,case ISNULL(SourceCode,' ')

when ' ' then 'BaseSource'

else SourceCode end

Can I expect that with this code Null values will first be converted to a blank spaces, and then to BaseSource within the current SourceCode column?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL SERVER` you can use a syntax like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET SourceCode = ISNULL(SourceCode, 'BaseSource')
```

Before `UPDATE` your live data you can try this SELECT:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SourceCode, 'BaseSource') FROM YourTable
```